# Change angle index label from google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have this code from google chart

```js
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Result code is:
[image]

How could I change the angle from horizontal to vertical for the values from the index label (8.94; 10.49, 19.3, 21.4)

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `change the angle from horizontal to vertical` ?

Comment: rotate text from 0 to 90, that here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qAtQj.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`style: 'line'` will change the layout
use `stem.color: 'transparent'` to "hide" the line

```
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: 'transparent'
          },
          style: 'line'
        },
```

see following working snippet...

```js
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        annotations: {
          stem: {
            color: 'transparent'
          },
          style: 'line'
        },
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Your code centerd the text right. Would it be possible to center the text in the middle?

Comment: unfortunately, no option for that, would have to change x coordinate manually, once the chart is drawn -- and the chart will put it back on every event, like hover...